# Do I need to hold the money for the “100 Million Credits” trophy?

Tags: achievements, neptunia-rebirth-2

One of the trophies in *Hyperdimension Neptunia Re;Birth 2* is

> **100 Million Credits**
>   Obtained a total of 100 million Credits.

Do I need to be holding 100 million credits at once to get the trophy? Or can I spend it and I just need to have earned 100 million as I played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PSN profiles](https://psnprofiles.com/guide/2427-hyperdimension-neptunia-rebirth2-trophy-guide#24-100-million-credits) trophy guide, the trophy is based on accumulated credits and you do not need to hold 100M credits at one to time

> As in ReBirth 1, you need to grind 100M credits and as in ReBirth 1, this trophy is cumulative so you don't need to reach 100M owned credits => credits spent also count towards this trophy

You can check your progress towards the trophy by viewing the Play Data in the Nedpedia

> You can check your progress by going to Nepedia, then choose Play Data, and go to Credits Held